# Android. Pid of active window for close

Tags: android, android-studio, root

How to get PID of active window? I want to close him.
For example, notification window with app error. Or frozen applications and notifications about "Not responding".

I'm looking for an analog of this method:

```
#!/bin/bash
gw=`xdotool getactivewindow`
gp=`xdotool getwindowpid $gw`
kill -9 $gp
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Do you want to get the foreground pid in shell or from an Android app (Java)?

Comment: Or in shell, of from an Android app (Java)